# Error: no such column: dateref

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to execute a query in a database I created, but it keeps saying that the column doesn't exist. here are the create table statements

```
    CREATE TABLE messages 
         (id integer primary key, 
          message text, 
          speaker text, 
          dateref int, 
          dateshow text,
          foreign key(speaker) references users(username)
    );

    CREATE TABLE subscribers 
         (subid integer primary key, 
          host text, 
          subscriber text, 
          int dateref,  
          foreign key(host) references users(username), 
          foreign key (subscriber) references users(username)
    );

    CREATE TABLE users
        (username text primary key, 
        password text);
```

and this is the query

```
    select 
        * 
    from 
        messages, subscribers 
    where 
        messages.speaker = subscribers.host and
        subscribers.dateref <= messages.dateref and 
        subscribers.subscriber = lee;
```

the weird thing is, even the query  select dateref from subscribers  results in the error        Error: no such column: dateref

Answer (score 1):

In your create table, you have "int dateref" instead of "dateref int".